# Strange behavior of animation constraints

Tags: rigging, constraints, inverse-kinematics

In my recent rigging tests i encountered some weird behavior when using animation constraints.

In this example you can see the foot is lagging some frames behind. Also if you cancel the animation, the bones are not snapping back to its initial position. This "bug" triggers (i believe) randomly. but you can force it by switching to the "iTaSC" IK solver and switching from animation to simulation and then back to the normal ik solver. if the "bug" is still not there, redo the procedure.

[image]

In this example the bones are switching to a wrong location when canceling the translation (<kbd>G</kbd>) by hitting the right mouse button.

[image]

I know that currently most of the constraints (like the "track to" constraint) are calculated after the IK constraint, so that using it can cause some glitches in the viewport. but i believe this is something more complex than that.
Is this a bug and should i write an offical bug report, or is it a known issue?

Here you can download both blend files: 
First:[Human_Rig_Bug](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5724585/3D/Pointer_riggtest_bug.blend)
Second:[Bug2](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5724585/3D/bug.blend)

Comment: This is 99.99% because of dependency issues. Check the console output.

Comment: Ok looked at the files. Your second example utilizes 2 IK constraints on 1 bone chain - don't do this. That's not how you should rig. The human rig is all wrong. Look at rigify rig how to rig legs. Follow only Blender cookie rigging tutorials and rigs and rigging from BlenderCloud and Rigify..most of the other stuff on the internet is crap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. tried to recreate my problems using rigify. got no problems. so it has to do something with my rig. i will analyse the rigify rig and adapt my own rig.

Comment: This happens when parenting conflicts with constraints. Usually it's copy transformation or inverse kinematics constraint related.